# PHP function does not print from the external file

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a small question. I have a php function which works perfectly when it is within the page. Here it is

```
$selectQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT product_code FROM product;";
$List = mysql_query( $selectQuery, $Connection ) or die("ERROR".mysql_error());

    while($Output = mysql_fetch_array($List))
    {
        echo "<option value='".$Output[0]."'>".$Output[0]."</option>";
    }
```

But when I include it to the file where I keep my functions and than call it from there it outputs nothing and everything which is below it is not outputted as well.
here is the function call:

```
<select name="Selector" >
  <option value="">--Select Product--</option>
  <?php printProductBox("SELECT DISTINCT product_code FROM product;"); ?>
  </select>
```

and here is the function in the function file which is also included earlier in the page:

```
function printProductBox($ParameterQuery){
     include ('DatabaseVariables.php');
     $List = mysql_query( $ParameterQuery, $Connection ) or die("ERROR".mysql_error());

     while($Output = mysql_fetch_array($List)){
        echo "<option value='".$Output[0]."'>".$Output[0]."</option>";
    }
}
```

The database credentials file is included both in the main page and in the function file (function file is also included in the page). 
Other functions from that file are working in the main page. So i wonder why there are problems with this function?

Does anybody have any clues about it?

Comment: What does the error log say?  What are the results of that query?

Comment: It appears that `$Connection` is not defined in the scope of your `printProductBox` function.

Comment: just everything which is below the fucntion call is not outputed

Comment: including the output which is supposed to be produced by function

Comment: $Connection is included in the file where the function is

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top, just in case ...

Comment: I've just added the connection credentials inside the function and still the same problem

Comment: shall I add ini_set('display_errors', '1'); in the main file or in the function files?

Comment: THe problem was solved. The Database variables were lacking in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the start of your function:

```
global $Connection;
```

Edit with new suggestion, which may help if the connection was already established, try replacing the older versions of these lines:

```
<?php printProductBox("SELECT DISTINCT product_code FROM product;", $Connection); ?>
```

and

```
function printProductBox($ParameterQuery, $Connection){
```

Comment: I have a specific file where I ceep connection details

Comment: shall I add global to all the variables there?

Comment: I adjusted the function this way `function printProductBox($ParameterQuery){
      include ('DatabaseVariables.php');
      $List = mysql_query( $ParameterQuery, $Connection ) or die("ERROR".mysql_error());
  
   while($Output = mysql_fetch_array($List)){
   echo "<option value='".$Output[0]."'>".$Output[0]."</option>";
  }
 }`

Comment: No because the others are being defined inside the function. But if you do not pass `$Connection` to it, or don't specify it as global so that it can see it, then the function is not able to utilize it. Instead of that `include` line, try the line I suggested... unless `DatabaseVariables.php` uses `mysql_connect()`

Comment: I will edit the main question better. it will be easier to understand

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but does `DatabaseVariables.php` just set the variables, or does it actually establish the connection? If the former, then it wont work, if the latter, then you might actually be making a 2nd connection which is undesirable and may not work depending on database settings. If your other code already has a `$Connection` previously in existence, you'll want to re-use it.

Answer (score 0):

the Problem was the lack of the credentials.
the credentials must be included in the function scope. I was wondering if there is a way to declare all the variables global. so I will not include the same files in the every single function.

Comment: If you dont return the call to `mysql_connect()` to a variable, the connection itself will be global. Then you only need to run `mysql_query($query)` and the rest takes care of itself. [PHP/mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) specifies that the second parameter is optional.